# How to mock the return value of class method imported from another class in Python?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I have these files:

```
/foo.py 
/foo2.py 
/test_food.py
```

in foo.py, I have this:

```
from foo2 import Foo2

class Foo(object):

    def GetFoo2(self):
        f = Foo2()
        return f.Get()
```

and in foo2.py, I have:

```
class Foo2(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = "eeee"

    def Get(self):
        return self.myvar
```

In test_foo.py,

```
import os, sys, json, pytest
from mock import *
from foo import Foo

def test_foo_ok(monkeypatch):

    monkeypatch.setattr(Foo, "GetFoo2", lambda x:"abc")
    f = Foo()
    result = f.GetFoo2()
    assert result == "abc"
```

So, in test_foo.py, I am able to mock or monkeypatch the method `GetFoo2()`.  However, instead of doing that, how can I mock the return value of Foo2's `Get()` method from test_foo.py without changing the code in foo.py and foo2.py?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you import using `from`, you can patch that module's namespace. Here is an example for your `test_foo_ok` function:

```
import os, sys, json, pytest
from mock import *
from foo import Foo

def test_foo_ok(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("foo.Foo2.Get", lambda x:"abc")
    f = Foo()
    result = f.GetFoo2()
    assert result == "abc"
```

See the [where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) section of the Mock library's documentation for more details. The same rules apply to pytest's monkeypatch.

Comment: I have tried that and I got this error at monkeypatch.setattr(...):

ImportError: No module named foo

Comment: @murvinlai what version of pytest? I tested this with 2.9.1 using your other files named as you described them.